# d3 tooltip/popup for multiple data series?

Tags: popup, d3.js, tooltip, mouseover

I'm looking for a way to display a tooltip/popup in d3 that shows all data for a certain timestamp. I'm displaying up to five data series at once and sometimes, but not always, there are data from two or more data series at the same timestamp, and those I want to show when move the mouse along the x-axis.

Can this be done?

Comment: You could use NVD3: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/line.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but none of the NVD3 examples shows more than one value for the same value on the x-axis. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: So what have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried the plain d3 tooltip, but can't figure out a simple way to get all data at a specific x-value from all data series to be stored i the text attribute. A mouseover event to get the x-coordinate and then scan all data series might work?

Comment: With the index you should be able to get the relevant data items from all your arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for my problem was to write some own functions that first get the x-position where I click on the chart, convert that to a valid timestamp. Then matching with nearest actual timestamp in the dataseries. Then I show a rect as a window with the data at that timestamp for all series that has data at that timestamp.